# How to make an expandable button toolbar

Tags: wpf

I have a navigation panel in the left hand side of my WPF application. I want to make a button (like in photoshop or a similar program) when you push it, it expands across the bounds and "on top" of the other controls (the center column) - and allowing the user to push a button. Just like in the ribbon bar.

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try Avalon Dock : http://avalondock.codeplex.com/ It gives you exactly what you want.